# How to set table name in Lucid Model?

Tags: adonis.js, lucid

The framework works by convention  (e.g. User → users), works well in english, but in anothers languages can be inelegant...

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Adonis.js v5 here's the soultion:

```
export default class User extends BaseModel {
  public static table = 'different_table_users'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_table

```
class User extends Model {
  static get table () {
    return 'my_users'
  }
}
```